# Javascript regular expression advice

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
/^[0-9]{8}([a-z]{1})?|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}([a-z]{1})?/
```

I'm trying to match the following patterns 12345678, 12345678a (any 1 character), 123-45-678, 123-45-678a (any 1 character).
The problem is if I enter 123456789, its still valid because of the first condition [0-9]{8}.  I searched if I can do use some kind of a AND operator but didn't find anything.  Is there a why to add to my regular expression for each condition to also match the length.  Example [0-9]{8} has to match the exact length also?  So 12345678 is correct but 123456789 fails?

**Update 1**

You guys have given me great examples.  It definitely made my expression smaller.  The only problem I still face is the following JavaScript code:

```
var regExp = new RegExp(/^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{3}[a-z]?/g);
var isValid = regExp.test('12345678');
isValid is true

var isValid = regExp.test('12345678d');
is valid 

the problem is if I enter
var isValid = regExp.test('12345678dd');
is also valid because of 12345678d

Since test() is used to find a match.  Is there a way to test the exact phrase of the regular expression so that 12345678dd fails?
```

**Update 2**
Ok, I totally missed the ending $ in everyones example.  My bad thank you so much for the help

Comment: Use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), also `{1}` is never necessary

Comment: When I add {0-8} in [0-9]{0-8} which I think your referring to I dont get a match for 12345678.  I'm doing my test on http://www.regexpal.com/ so when I copy the expression it doesnt copy the /^

Comment: regarding your update: just add $ to the end of the regex, it's the complement of ^ and means: "match end of string", so use: /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{3}[a-z]?$/g

Comment: be warned that your regex also matches 123-45678 or 12345-678 if you don't use Rahul's or Sebastian's approach.

Comment: @adviner The regex that you are using mentioned in your update is incorrect. You are missing the `$` as Anton mentioned. Please check my answer below.

Comment: Thanks I realized that the $ was missing.  I mentioned that in my second update.  I really appreciate your help, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of fixing your regex is:

```
/^\d{3}(-?)\d{2}\1\d{3}[a-z]?$/
```

**Explanation:**
`^` = start of string
`\d` = any 1 digit from 0 to 9, same as `[0-9]`
`{3}` = exactly 3 occurrences of the previous thing, in this case it is `\d`
`-?` = optional `-`
`(<part-of-regex-here>)` = captures a match which is numbered starting from 1, it can be referred to in the regex as `\1`
`[a-z]` = any lowercase alphabet
`$` = end of string

[**Demo on RegexPal.com**](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94620)

**In response to Update 1:**

If you try my regex:

```js
var regExp = new RegExp(/^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{3}[a-z]?$/);
var isValid = regExp.test('12345678');
console.log(isValid);

isValid = regExp.test('12345678d');
console.log(isValid);

isValid = regExp.test('12345678dd');
console.log(isValid);
```

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: `/^\d{3}(-?)\d{2}\1\d{3}[a-z]?$/g` - requires either no dashes or both, not just one.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks! That does improve the regex! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `/^(?:\d{8}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{3})[a-z]?$/`, note the anchors for start (^) and end ($) of the string.

I also used `\d` instead of `[0-9]` cause it's shorter and imho more readable and put the `[a-z]?` outside the alternation. There is never a need to use `{1}`.

Here's a demo on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fV5gP3/1)